# Syntax ordering in Java

Tags: java, syntax

The following two syntax orderings are valid within Java. Why are both allowed and is there a preferred syntax order?

```
  private final static String consultantType = "consultantType";
  private static final String consultantId = "consultantId";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any order is allowed because there is no value in restricting the order, so why bother imposing the burden of remember a spurious ordering on the programmer?

It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever which order you use. Pick the one you prefer, use it consistently, and move on to a more interesting problem.

For what it's worth, I think "private static final" is probably more common.

Comment: That is a good point, thank's for the answer will accept it as valid after the 10 min. requirement. P.S there is a difference between a question and problem! this was not a problem rather a question to prepare for the interview question when it happens :) - Duncan

Answer (score 8):

The [Java Language Specification section 8.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) states:

> *If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for FieldModifier.*

The production for `FieldModifier` is:

```
FieldModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    static final transient volatile
```

So in your case, it is customary to use `private static final`, although any order is valid.

Answer (score 0):

**Any order is valid**. Therefore, [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) labeled with a warning when it encounters with a modifiers outside the following order. See the [`ModifierOrder`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) check.

1. `public`
2. `protected`
3. `private`
4. `abstract`
5. `static`
6. `final`
7. `transient`
8. `volatile`
9. `synchronized`
10. `native`
11. `strictfp`